# iPhone events handling

Tags: iphone, events, touch, drag

does anybody know how can I handle the events(touch, drag) in UIApplicationDelegate instead of UIView?

Comment: It is possible, use NSObject class

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to respond to touch events, a class must inherit from UIResponder. So to start you would have to make your app delegate a subclass of UIResponder. However, it's not going to be in the responder chain for any views or view controllers so it will never receive touch events.

Why would you want your app delegate to handle touches. That is not what the app delegate is for. It sounds like you've got a design problem.